# Accessing Checkboxes inside a Qtableview

Tags: c++, qt

I m new to `Qt` and i m trying to add a `QCheckbox` Column to my `QTableView` using `SetIndexWidget()` as follows:

```
QSqlQueryModel * model = new QSqlQueryModel();

model->setQuery("select * from Rendezvous");
model->insertColumn(0);
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr(""));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("ID"));
model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Date"));
model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Heure"));
model->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Type"));
model->setHeaderData(5, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Description"));
model->setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("ID Client"));
ui->tableView_RDV->setModel(model);
ui->tableView_RDV->resizeColumnToContents(0);
for(int p=0;p<model->rowCount();p++)
{
    ui->tableView_RDV->setIndexWidget(model->index(p,0),new QCheckBox());
}
```

This adds a Checkbox to my Table and i can interact with it but i have no idea how to check Which Lines in my `QTableView` have Checked `QCheckboxe`s.

I appreciate any kind of indication to how to do this.

Comment: What is the type of `model`?

Comment: i edited with the exact piece of code .. it's a QueryModel

Comment: Why you don't want to use `Qt::CheckStateRole`? Using widgets in view is a very big overhead. P.S. `model->setData( index, Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole );`

Comment: You are probably right i'm getting ahead of myself i should just use Qt:CheckStateRole .. thanks

Comment: @New_ToQT i post it as an answer, with sample. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Qt::CheckStateRole`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html#2-2-extending-the-read-only-example-with-roles) for displaying checkboxes. It is much faster, and corresponds to Qt MVC:

```
for(int p=0;p<model->rowCount();p++)
{
    auto checked = SomeLogic ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
    auto index = model->index( p, 0 );
    model->setData( index, checked, Qt::CheckStateRole );
}
```

Note: checkbox will be shown only if you directy specify `Qt::CheckStateRole` with non-empty value. If you will set it to an empty `QVariant()`, checkbox will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet may help you:

```
for(int p=0;p<model->rowCount();p++)
{
    QCheckBox* tmp = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(ui->tableView_RDV->indexWidget(model->index(p,0)));
    if(tmp != NULL && tmp.isChecked())
    {
        //Do what you wants when it is checked
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**
For using `qobject_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` after comment from *Dmitry Sazonov* and information available at [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/59498/qobject_cast-vs-dynamic_cast)

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is much slower, than `qobject_cast`. And this will not work in case of using some filter/proxy models.